# Controller AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Es posible hacer esto:

```
var self = this;
        //self.emp = {nCodEmpleadoPk:null, cnombres: '', capellidoPaterno: '', capellidoMaterno: '', cSexo: '',cnumDoc:'',ncodArea:'',ncodCargo:'',nEstado:''};

         self.emp = {nCodEmpleadoPk:null,cNombres: '',cUsuario:'', cApellidoPaterno: '', cApellidoMaterno: '', cSexo: '',cNumDoc:'',nEstado:''};


        self.emps = [];
        self.buscar={cApellidoPaterno:'',cApellidoMaterno:''};
        self.busc=[];
```

Tengo 2 formularios uno de registro y otro de búsqueda `self.buscar` lo quiero usar para búsqueda, pero usa algunos parámetros de `self.emp`

Comment: Y cual es la pregunta o duda?

Comment: quiero pasar 2 parametros de este formulario a mi controller